# How to remove labels from Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

Removing labels is a nightmare! When one asks for instructions, you invariably get directed to something that isn't there!

**How is it done?**

Viewing London is a nightmare - so confusing.

Comment: you can use https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/?hl=en